# Is it possible to obtain trace of FVP using DS5 v5.21.1 ultimate(Evaluation version)

Tags: trace, ds-5

I am using DS5 v5.21.1 ultimate(Evaluation Version), I am trying to capture trace of  ARM cortex A8 Fast model ("ARM FVP (Installed with DS-5) -> Cortex-A8 -> Bare Metal ->Debug -> Debug Cortex-A8") and have also added "--plugin MTS" option in the Connections -> Bare Metal Debug -> Model parameters.

While debugging the fast model get terminated abruptly stating "Failed to capture trace. A communication error has occurred between host and trace unit"

Following are the console logs:

```
 terminal_1: Listening for serial connection on port 5003

 terminal_2: Listening for serial connection on port 5000

 terminal_0: Listening for serial connection on port 5002

 terminal_3: Listening for serial connection on port 5001

 WARNING: baseboard.mmc: MMC backing store file mmc.dat could not be used

 When loading plugin "C:\Program Files\DS-5 v5.21.1\sw\models\bin\MTS.dll":

 Error loading plugin: The specified procedure could not be found.

 INFO: baseboard.mmc backing store: no image file connected

 CADI server started listening to port 7000

 CADI server is reported on port 7000

 Simulation is terminating. Reason: Simulation requested shutdown
```

Note:

```
 I am runnning on a Windows XP Professional SP3 (32 bit ) Machine.
```

Can we capture trace of a fast model with DS5 ultimate evaluation version ?

Comment: Solved. Windows XP has been deprecated for DS5. Found success after running on Windows 7 Machine